# Add values in reactjs form

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create more than one form and add all values in one variable with different objects

```
export default function FormView() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<ResumeViewType>({
    contact: {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      country: '',
      website: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      linkedIn: ''
    },
    projects: {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      image: ''
    }
  });


  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<ErrorsType>({});

  const handleChange = (e: { target: { name: string; value: string } }) => {
    setValues((prevInput) => ({
      ...prevInput,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Contact
        values={values}
        errors={errors}
        handleChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to add properties in different objects and get them by key

Comment: Do you mean that the `FormView` is the basic form so other Forms can you it as base and add their own inputs?

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleChange = (key: string) => {
  return (e: { target: { name: string; value: string } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [key]: {
        ...prev[key as keyof ResumeViewType],
        [name]: value
      }
    }));
  };
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).